# How to check the background graphic check box checked by default usning the code html or css

Tags: html, css

Step 1: First open a page
Step 2: click ctrl+P then print preview page will be open.
Step 3: down side the background graphics check box should be checked.

In the attachment I have shown UN-checked check box in print preview page.
Can any one let me help for selecting this check box by default using any html or css code.

[image]

Because the if the check box is unchecked I am unable to see the background color in the print preview and also in the printed copy.
Or is there any work around for this?

Comment: It is not an html css problem.why did you tag those?

Comment: I know it is not a problem.
My question is there any way to make it checked by writing code in html or css?

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox will be checked on page load,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />

$(window).load(function(){
 $('#checkbox').prop( 'checked', true ); 
});
```

It may help you...